# How to get authorization code for OAuth2 on heroku? input() cannot be used

Tags: python, flask, heroku, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api

## USING GMAIL API AND HEROKU FOR HOSTING

I am a beginner at this. I am making a server-side webapp. I am trying to complete the authorization process using the following piece of code but flow.fetch_token is a bit confusing. I dont know how to get authorization code without using input() in python.

`

```
if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            # these three lines below were added for heroku
            creds = json.loads(os.environ.get('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'))
            with open('credentials.json', 'w') as fp:
                json.dump(creds, fp)


            flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            flow.redirect_uri = 'https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground'

            #write code for getting credentials on heroku without using input

            authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
                # Enable offline access so that you can refresh an access token without
                # re-prompting the user for permission. Recommended for web server apps.
                access_type='offline',
                # Enable incremental authorization. Recommended as a best practice.
                include_granted_scopes='true')

            print('Please go to this URL: {}'.format(authorization_url))

            # Request authorization_code
            authorization_response = input('Enter the authorization code: ')
            flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
            creds = flow.credentials
            # Save the credentials for the next run
            with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
                pickle.dump(creds, token)

        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
```

`

I cannot use the below line in heroku. I am getting an EOF error

```
authorization_response = input('Enter the authorization code: ')
```

Comment: Edit your question to explain what your goal is. You are using code that is intended for devices that do not have a browser. Review the left panel of this page to select the type of app you are building: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2

Comment: umm...a server side web app

Comment: this is not an "offline" authentication flow. You'll need to change the flow to the server based one. See [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server) for details.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't SHOUT AT US. If you need to emphasize something you can [do it with Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).